# time returns negative numbers

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, quick.db

I am trying to create a 24hr timer on a database using quick.db, but my timer isn't ticking, and time logs negative number.

```js
const db = require('quick.db');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ms = require('parse-ms');

let timer = await db.fetch(`daily_timer`);
let timeout = 86400000;

if (timer !== null && timeout - (Date.now() * -2 - timer) > 0) {
    let time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() * -2 - timer));
    console.log(time);
    etc..
};
```

If the `* -2` is removed from `let time = ..` then it logs everything as negative.
`Date.now()` returns as normal.

console.log for time:
`{ days: -18950, hours: -9, minutes: -56, seconds: -51, milliseconds: -673, microseconds: -0, nanoseconds: -936 }`

console.log for Date.now():
`1637488611676`

Any help would be appreciated, as I really have no idea why the time is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unix timestamp `86400000` represents the `27th of September 1972`.
With `timeout - Date.now()` you are asking, how much time do i need to add to the current date, to get to the `27th of September 1972`. Since the current date is FAR beyond `27th of September 1972`, the time you need to add will be negative.